# Which scripts can I run from the following piece of package.json file without breaking anything?

Tags: material-ui, open-source, package.json

I apologize in advance if my question is inappropriate. I want to contribute to Open Source projects in the future. I've cloned one repo (MUI) and It feels like I'm not ready to contribute for now even though I know what package.json is and what it does. However in this case the scripts section is pretty clunky and I'm a bit afraid of trying one of these scripts. Is there a way to run something like "npm start" in create-react-app so I could explore the project? I would really appreciate your help.

```
"scripts": 

  {
    "proptypes": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=development babel-node --extensions \".tsx,.ts,.js\" ./scripts/generateProptypes.ts",
    "deduplicate": "node scripts/deduplicate.js",
    "benchmark:browser": "yarn workspace benchmark browser",
    "build:codesandbox": "lerna run --parallel --scope \"@mui/*\" build",
    "release:version": "lerna version --no-changelog --no-push --no-git-tag-version --force-publish=@mui/core-downloads-tracker",
    "release:build": "lerna run --parallel --scope \"@mui/*\" build",
    "release:changelog": "node scripts/releaseChangelog",
    "release:publish": "lerna publish from-package --dist-tag latest --contents build",
    "release:publish:dry-run": "lerna publish from-package --dist-tag latest --contents build --registry=\"http://localhost:4873/\"",
    "release:tag": "node scripts/releaseTag",
    "docs:api": "rimraf ./docs/pages/**/api-docs ./docs/pages/**/api && yarn docs:api:build",
    "docs:api:build": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=development __NEXT_EXPORT_TRAILING_SLASH=true babel-node --extensions \".tsx,.ts,.js\" ./docs/scripts/buildApi.ts",
    "docs:build": "yarn workspace docs build",
    "docs:build-sw": "yarn workspace docs build-sw",
    "docs:build-color-preview": "babel-node scripts/buildColorTypes",
    "docs:deploy": "yarn workspace docs deploy",
    "docs:dev": "yarn workspace docs dev",
    "docs:export": "yarn workspace docs export",
    "docs:icons": "yarn workspace docs icons",
    "docs:size-why": "cross-env DOCS_STATS_ENABLED=true yarn docs:build",
    "docs:start": "yarn workspace docs start",
    "docs:i18n": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=development babel-node --extensions \".tsx,.ts,.js\" ./docs/scripts/i18n.js",
    "docs:typescript": "yarn docs:typescript:formatted --watch",
    "docs:typescript:check": "yarn workspace docs typescript",
    "docs:typescript:formatted": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=development babel-node --extensions \".tsx,.ts,.js\" ./docs/scripts/formattedTSDemos",
    "docs:mdicons:synonyms": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=development babel-node --extensions \".tsx,.ts,.js\" ./docs/scripts/updateIconSynonyms && yarn prettier",
    "extract-error-codes": "cross-env MUI_EXTRACT_ERROR_CODES=true lerna run --parallel build:modern",
    "template:screenshot": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=development babel-node --extensions \".tsx,.ts,.js\" ./docs/scripts/generateTemplateScreenshots",
    "install:codesandbox": "PLAYWRIGHT_SKIP_BROWSER_DOWNLOAD=1 yarn install --ignore-engines",
    "jsonlint": "node ./scripts/jsonlint.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --cache --report-unused-disable-directives --ext .js,.ts,.tsx --max-warnings 0",
    "lint:ci": "eslint . --report-unused-disable-directives --ext .js,.ts,.tsx --max-warnings 0",
    "stylelint": "stylelint --reportInvalidScopeDisables --reportNeedlessDisables docs/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}",
    "markdownlint": "markdownlint \"**/*.md\" --config .markdownlint.jsonc",
    "prettier": "node ./scripts/prettier.js",
    "prettier:all": "node ./scripts/prettier.js write",
    "size:snapshot": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./scripts/sizeSnapshot/create",
    "size:why": "yarn size:snapshot --analyze",
    "start": "yarn && yarn docs:dev",
    "t": "node test/cli.js",
    "test": "yarn lint && yarn typescript && yarn test:coverage",
    "test:coverage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_ENV=coverage nyc --reporter=text mocha 'packages/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'docs/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'scripts/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'test/utils/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "test:coverage:ci": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_ENV=coverage nyc --reporter=lcov mocha 'packages/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'docs/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'scripts/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'test/utils/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "test:coverage:html": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_ENV=coverage nyc --reporter=html mocha 'packages/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'docs/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'scripts/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'test/utils/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "test:e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn test:e2e:build && concurrently --success first --kill-others \"yarn test:e2e:run\" \"yarn test:e2e:server\"",
    "test:e2e:build": "webpack --config test/e2e/webpack.config.js",
    "test:e2e:dev": "concurrently \"yarn test:e2e:build --watch\" \"yarn test:e2e:server\"",
    "test:e2e:run": "mocha --config test/e2e/.mocharc.js 'test/e2e/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "test:e2e:server": "serve test/e2e",
    "test:e2e-website": "playwright test test/e2e-website --config test/e2e-website/playwright.config.ts",
    "test:e2e-website:dev": "cross-env PLAYWRIGHT_TEST_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 playwright test test/e2e-website --config test/e2e-website/playwright.config.ts",
    "test:karma": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test:karma:profile": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start test/karma.conf.profile.js",
    "test:regressions": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production yarn test:regressions:build && concurrently --success first --kill-others \"yarn test:regressions:run\" \"yarn test:regressions:server\"",
    "test:regressions:build": "webpack --config test/regressions/webpack.config.js",
    "test:regressions:dev": "concurrently \"yarn test:regressions:build --watch\" \"yarn test:regressions:server\"",
    "test:regressions:run": "mocha --config test/regressions/.mocharc.js --delay 'test/regressions/**/*.test.js'",
    "test:regressions:server": "serve test/regressions",
    "test:umd": "node packages/mui-material/test/umd/run.js",
    "test:unit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha 'packages/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'docs/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'scripts/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}' 'test/utils/**/*.test.{js,ts,tsx}'",
    "test:argos": "node ./scripts/pushArgos.js",
    "typescript": "lerna run --no-bail --parallel typescript",
    "typescript:ci": "lerna run --concurrency 7 --no-bail --no-sort typescript",
    "validate-declarations": "babel-node --extensions \".ts\" scripts/validateTypescriptDeclarations.ts",
    "generate-codeowners": "node scripts/generateCodeowners.mjs"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `start` command

```
"start": "yarn && yarn docs:dev"
```

You should be able to run `yarn start` in your console.
On the topic "what if you break something", well its cloned local copy, so what... just delete it and clone it again if you need to.